# How do I download the Honeycomb SDK preview?

Tags: android

I keep getting a "File not found" error in the SDK Manager when I try to download the SDK Preview for Honeycomb.  Same thing happens with both http and https.  Any advice?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Having the same problem, and the torrent below not being seeded (it downloads until 21% and then it stops) I thought I'll add my opionion about the issue. Here it comes: it highly sucks of Google to just pull the file like this without any explanation whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

i believe you need to download android 3.0 or launch Android SDK and AVD Manager and update it.
refer this : http://developer.android.com/sdk/preview/index.html

Edit : 
you need to update your eclipse first : help -> check for updates.
then start Android SDK and AVD Manager and download all available contents there.
it works for me.

Comment: It was available until this morning from the reports I have found.  When I open Android SKD Manager, I am prompted to install Honeycomb (located at the aforementioned URL) and get a file not found error.  (Just as the poster of this question), there is no reference to why it was pulled, if it was flawed, at least let us deal with it, I would love to know the reason for pulling it?  I was sick last week, finally feel well enough to jump into this and it's too late.. :(

Comment: ya, just realized that. no chances to try until today and show FILE NOT FOUND.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the reason they removed it:
[NOOKcolor gets treated to an early taste of Honeycomb](http://androidandme.com/2011/01/news/manufacturers/nookcolor-gets-treated-to-an-early-taste-of-honeycomb/)

Answer (score 0):

Google took it down for some reason. I doubt it was because of the NOOKcolor. Maybe it has something to do with the announcement from the 2nd of February.